# How to set up curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use some SMS gateway and it require me to use curl to post a message to their server.

How do I set up curl on a windows and linux server?

I guess curl is some PHP library?

Which files do I need to include?

Where will I get those files?

Answer (score 6):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) can be used as a [PHP module](http://www.php.net/curl), but you can also install it as a regular command line application and execute [curl commands](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) as [separate processes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

If you want to test your server support for either of these, try this:

```
<?php

//test for extension
if (extension_loaded("curl"))
{
    echo "cURL extension is loaded<br>";
}    
else
{
    echo "cURL extension is not available<br>";
}

//test for command line app
echo "cURL command line version:<br><pre>";
echo `curl --version`;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: i have a acccount with some hosting company where i host my site.How wil i come to know if curl is installed or not? Is it already available on  my server?How can i make out

Comment: @unknown upload a script that says <?PHP phpinfo(); ?>, load it in the browser, and search the output for "curl" -- if it's installed, you'll  find a section devoted to its configuration